# Select the same columns from multiple DataFrames in a Dictionary of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, series

I need to extract the same column from multiple DataFrames in a Dictionary and save them as a DataFrame so that each column name is labelled as the key in the Dictionary.

By extracting the 'close' column from each DataFrame in the Dictionary I end up with the Series below:

| date | close |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-03-06 04:00:00 | 1 |
| 2023-03-06 05:00:00 | 2 |
| 2023-03-06 06:00:00 | 2 |

And I need to make a DataFrame with n columns that looks like this:

| date | SPY | QQQ | SMH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-06 04:00:00 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2023-03-06 05:00:00 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 2023-03-06 06:00:00 | 3 | 2 | 3 |

The number of tickers varies.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the dictionary you have created is called `d`, the corresponding empty data frame is called `final_df` and one of your dataframes with the data is called `spy_df`

You can simply loop through the dictionary like this:

```
for idx, val in d.items():
    final_df[idx] = val['close'] #idx would be the key value in the dictionary 

final_df.index = spy_df.index
```

Comment: for idx, val in data.items():
    final_df[idx] = val['close'] #idx would be the key value in the dictionary

Comment: ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

Comment: This is the same error I get for every way I've tried. I've tried pd.concat, pd.join, pd.merge, etc. It's been almost 12 hours now, no idea where I'm going wrong here,

Comment: @AndyVisser Then please provide a a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) that replicates your problem. Otherwise it's just guessing around.